# Error in boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: All type of module not found required org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Todo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("http://google.com");
            System.out.println("driver.getTitle()");
            driver.close();
    }
}
```

This is the code. I had build the path as per the steps then also program is not running. Even I had added selenium standalone file then also error occurs. And one more thing I am having java-17

I tried to run the program as given but error occur and expected to run proper program

Comment: Are you using Maven project or Java project? If Java project, did you add the dependencies in Class path instead of Module path?

Comment: I am using java project. which kind of dependencies i have to add and can you provide the steps of adding dependencies? I tried to add the dependencies previously but got failed to add.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of your Java project's 'Java Build Path > Libraries' tab from the project's Properties?

Comment: yes I post that too

Comment: I can't see the screenshot here.

Comment: I am new in this website....so I am not able to share screenshot with you...but in build path>libraries>module path>add'external jar'>selenium json ,driver ,safari kind of file>JRE system library(java-17)>class path>selenium server-4.7.2-jar and other file is selenium standalone file

Comment: If you don't understand then please let me know

Answer (score 0):

You've added the dependencies in the Modulepath, you have to add the dependencies in Classpath, check the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: ok then what i have to add in classpath?

Comment: Now I am getting error in the code of ' import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;